# jQuery validate isn't firing in asp.net app

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

I haven't used jQuery in several months and have become rusty.  I'm trying to use the validation plugin and it is not firing like it should.  Here is the code from my project:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-validate.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/createUser.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#frmCreateUser").validate({
            rules: {
                txtNewUsername: {
                    required: true
                },
                txtConfirmUsername: {
                    required: true,
                    //minlength: 5,
                    equalTo: "#txtNewUsername"
                },
                txtNewPassword: {
                    required: true,
                    //email: true
                },
                txtConfirmNewPassword: {
                    required: true,
                    equalTo: "#txtNewPassword"
                }
                //agree: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                txtNewUsername: "Please enter username",
                txtConfirmNewUsername: "Please confirm username",

                txtNewPassword: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    //minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                },
                txtConfirmNewPassword: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    //minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                    equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
                }
                //email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            }
        });

        $("#txtContactPhone").mask("(999) 999-9999", { placeholder: " " });

    });
</script>
</head>

<body>

   <form id="frmCreateUser" runat="server">
     <div style="align-content:center">
         <h1>Alabama Debt Recovery System</h1>
          <br />
          <h3><u>Create User</u></h3>
      </div>
      <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>New Username:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtNewUsername" runat="server" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Confirm New Username:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmUsername" runat="server" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <%--<td>Password:</td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" /></td>--%>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>New Password:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtNewPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Confirm New Password:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmNewPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><br /></td>
                        <td><br /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><br /></td>
                        <td><br /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><br /></td>
                        <td><br /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><br /></td>
                        <td><br /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <%--<tr>
                        <td>UserId:</td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lblUserId" runat="server" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username:</td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" /></td>
                    </tr>--%>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Entity Name:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtEntityName" runat="server" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Entity Address:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtEntityAddress" runat="server" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Entity City:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtEntityCity" runat="server" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Entity State:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddEntityState" runat="server" DataTextField="StateName" DataValueField="StateId" />
                            <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtEntityState" runat="server" MaxLength="2" Width="20px" />--%>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;Entity Zip:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEntityZip" runat="server" Width="50px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Contact First Name:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtContactFirstName" runat="server" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Contact Last Name:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtContactLastName" runat="server" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Contact Phone:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtContactPhone" runat="server" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Contact Email:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtContactEmail" runat="server" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Confirm Email:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmEmail" runat="server" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Using a Third Party:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblThirdParty" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" TextAlign="Right">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="YES" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="NO" />
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><br /></td>
                        <td><br /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" /></td>
                        <td><asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><h4>You are logged in as:</h4><asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Likely more insightful to look at the rendered HTML and the browsers F12 error console.

Comment: Agree with @AlexK.'s  comment. check the IDs of your generated html as they may not actually match your jQuery selectors.

Comment: $('#<%=Page.Form.ClientID%>').validate as well as setting ClientIDMode='static' on form elements that runat='server'

Comment: As stated already, check the ***rendered*** HTML and verify that the **`name`** attribute matches what you've declared within `.validate()`.

Comment: I checked the rendered html and the name attribute matches the declarations in the jquery.  Everything looks like it should work fine and I'm not getting any errors in the javascript console on chrome.  I have the rendered html and jquery working in a fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/L3cd1krr/2/   and full screen  http://jsfiddle.net/L3cd1krr/2/embedded/result/

Comment: You need to learn asp.NET very well dude .

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's by ID, not NAME

Comment: The ID and Name attributes render with the same value, it's like the jquery isn't firing but it works fine on fiddle.

Comment: There are no errors in the javascript console (F12 error console).